# Integrating Factors Help

Tags: integrating-factor

Studying for a test and I am a bit confused with this problem.

$$y'+\frac y{(2xy-e^{-2y})}=0$$

It says that you can rewrite it as the following:

$${(2xy-e^{-2x})}dy+ydx=0$$

I understand that you multiply both sides by the denominator but I am confused as to how it causes the change of variable in the exponential?

And on the answer sheet instead of doing $M_y$ and $N_x$, it does $M_y$ and $N_y$, giving this as the value for $N_y$:

$$N_y=2y$$

I understand the method but it almost seems like the answer sheet is wrong. Because then it says:

$$\frac {\partial \mu}{\partial x}=\frac {M_y-N_x}M=\frac {1-2y}y$$

It just doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever how you get these values?

Comment: Just realized this. working on it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question it seems it's just a typo
$$y'+\frac y{(2xy-e^{-2y})}=0$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}+\frac y{(2xy-e^{-2y})}=0$$
$${dy}+\frac y{(2xy-e^{-2y})}dx=0$$
$${(2xy-e^{-2y})}{dy}+ ydx=0$$
For the integrating factor you only need a function of y

To make it exact...
$${(2xy-e^{-2y})}{dy}+ ydx=0$$
$$2y{(2xy-e^{-2y})}{dy}+ 2y^2dx=0$$
$$Qdy+Pdx=0$$
We need for exactness that :
$$\frac  {\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac  {\partial Q}{\partial x}=0$$
$$4y-4y=0$$

Comment: So you differentiate M with respect to x to get 2y, then multiply through and solve the exact?

Comment: @RyanGodbey  I added some line you need exactness so you mutliply by a function of x or y or both here a function of y is needed

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks!

Comment: yw @RyanGodbey ......for the last line its just the formula for the integrating factor that depends on y only

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some typos occurred: the re-writing should say
$${(2xy-e^{-2y})}dy+ydx=0$$
which would give
$$N_x = 2y$$
matching up with the final line. Your understanding of the method seems correct!